# Showing $(M \otimes_K N) \otimes_K K_n \cong (M \otimes_K K_n) \otimes_{K_n} (N \otimes_K K_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K = \mathbb{C}[[h]]$ be the algebra of formal power series of the complex field and let $K_n = \frac{\mathbb{C}[[h]]}{(h^n)}$. I'm trying to understand the following isomorphism:

$(M \otimes_K N) \otimes_K K_n \cong (M \otimes_K K_n) \otimes_{K_n} (N \otimes_K K_n)$

Thanks!

Comment: You might find it helpful to think of $\cdot \otimes_K K_n$ as an ["extension" of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings#Extension_of_scalars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion holds for every commutative algebra $B$ over a commutative ring $A$ and $A$-modules $M,N$.
This follows from this chain of $B$-module isomorphisms:
\begin{align}
(M\otimes_AB)\otimes_B(N\otimes_AB)
&\xrightarrow\sim M\otimes_A(B\otimes_B(N\otimes_AB)\\
&\xrightarrow\sim M\otimes_A(N\otimes_AB)\\
&\xrightarrow\sim(M\otimes_AN)\otimes_AB\\
\end{align}

Comment: $B \otimes_B (N \otimes_A B) \cong (N \otimes_A B)$? Hmm... I'm sure this is obvious but for some reason I'm not seeing it

Comment: For every $B$-module $E$ we have $B\otimes_BE\cong E$: this is the canonical isomorphism $b\otimes e\mapsto eb$.

Comment: But it $N \otimes_A B$ a $B$ module?

Comment: Yes, with $B$-module structured inherited from that of $B$.

Comment: Right, I was thinking it had to get past $N$ somehow >.<